# Add markers from .kml file to an mbtiles map

Tags: kml, mbtiles

I have an offline map GoogleSatellite.mbtiles.

and a .kml file with thousands of points..

How can I combine the two files into ONE single .mbtiles file?

Is there any utility that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

QGIS has a tool *Generate XYZ Tiles (MBTiles)* that will convert the current map canvas to an MBTiles file.

[image]

Comment: hello
thanks, is there any way to do it other then QGIS?